# IOS 8 Default (Swift Xcode Tutorial) vs IOS 7 (Objective C Xcode Tutorial)

Tags: ios, xcode, ios8

I am currently trying to code using Swift for IOS8 (anyone else doing this?)

So far I found the tutorial for IOS7 linked here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/FirstTutorial.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011343-CH3-SW1
(if anyone has the IOS8 tutorial please do link me!)

In it, it says to go under the "Supporting Files" folder and "To look at the main.m source file" and erase 3 lines of code in order to prevent Xcode from displaying the default white blank screen.

In IOS8 however, they use Swift instead of Objective C, and there is only 1 file under Supporting Files: Info.plist.

Does anyone know what to do to stop XCode from showing its default screen every time I run my code, no matter what I write?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tutorial doesn't say anything about deleting lines from `main.m`.

It says you should delete three lines from `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` in `XYZAppDelegate.m` to make it look like this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    return YES;
}
```

If you've created a new project using the “Empty Application” template and Swift, then you need to delete lines from the `application(didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` method in `AppDelegate.swift` to make it look like this:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: NSDictionary?) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```